# Awk strftime on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash, awk

The following command on my Mac (10.6) gives me an undefined function error:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{now=strftime("%D", systime()); print now}'
awk: calling undefined function strftime
 source line number 1
```

On a Red Hat system, I get the expected result:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{now=strftime("%D", systime()); print now}'
12/01/09
```

What's the deal here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

strftime is a GNU gawk extension. If you want to use strftime, download GNU gawk and install on your Mac. Otherwise, there are other tools like Perl/Python you can use. Check if you have them on your Mac

Comment: I installed gawk, mawk and nawk using MacPorts, but I still get the same error.

Comment: sudo port install gawk
I can confirm that gawk is in the correct PATH, but can't find any reference to strftime

Comment: Correct syntax after installing gawk was

gawk 'BEGIN{now=strftime("%D", systime()); print now}'

Comment: My text book was using awk rather than gawk, so I was confused as to why it still wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 12):

Use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) and then just run `brew install gawk`

Answer (score 4):

You're relying on an extension to awk that's present in whichever variant (gawk, mawk, nawk, etc.) your Red Hat system happens to be using.  See [the Standard Unix Specification's awk description](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) for what you can expect as a baseline for awk.